# Testing if some value is null

Tags: c#

I have the following code, but i got a problem. Within my While, a have to test if r["Varandas"] is not null. In a specific imovel_id, the r["Varandas"] is null, but still passing through my code and then I got an exception error because can't parse to int the r["Varandas"] because is null, but why he pass through my first IF inside my While loop ?

```
        string s = "SELECT * "
            + "FROM San_Imovel_Caracteristica "
            + "WHERE Imovel_Id = " + imovel_id + " ";

        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(conn.Con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, c);
        c.Open();
        SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (r.Read())
        {
            if (r["Varandas"] != null)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(r["Varandas"].ToString()) > 0)
                {
                    XmlElement itemImovel1 = doc.CreateElement("itemImovel");
                    caracteristicasImovel.AppendChild(itemImovel1);
                    itemImovel1.InnerText = "varanda";
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: @habib.osu If only they were all this easy ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*null* value from database has its own special type:

```
if (r["Varandas"] != DBNull.Value && r["Varandas"] != null)
```

To make it more elegant you can write some simple function or even extension for the DataRow class.

Answer (score 1):

Need to check `DbNull.Value`

```
 if (r["Varandas"] != DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to these wonderful answers which are correct, I would like to add few things regarding null and DBNull.

- null is `not` an instance of any type. DBnull is instance of
  `System.DBnull`.
- null represents invalid reference where as DbNull represents
  nonexistent value in DB.
- DBnull is what db providers provide for nonexistant value in a table.

Answer (score 0):

It could have value of  `DbNull.Value`

Comment: stackoverflow is cool, asked me for a capcha before submitting an answer :)

Comment: and you proved that you are not the robot :)

Answer (score 0):

try comparing it to DBNull.Value

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(r.Read())
{
  object o = r["Varandas"];
  if ((o != null) && (o != DbNull.Value))
  {
    // rest of your code
  }
}
```

A `DbNull.Value` is not the same as a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :

```
string s = "SELECT * "
        + "FROM San_Imovel_Caracteristica "
        + "WHERE Imovel_Id = " + imovel_id + " ";

    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(conn.Con);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, c);
    c.Open();
    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    int outint;

    while (r.Read())
    {
        Object o = r["Varandas"];
        if (o != null && o != DbNull.Value)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(o.ToString(), out outint))
            {
                XmlElement itemImovel1 = doc.CreateElement("itemImovel");
                caracteristicasImovel.AppendChild(itemImovel1);
                itemImovel1.InnerText = "varanda";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
/// <summary>
/// This function tries to cast the input object to a integer or returns the default value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="objInput">object to check</param>
/// <param name="intDefault">optional default value</param>
/// <returns>Object cast to string or default value</returns>
public static int ValueOrDefaultForInteger(object objInput, int intDefault = 0)
{ 
 if (objInput == DBNull.Value | objInput == null)
    return intDefault;
 return Convert.ToInt32(objInput);
}
```

I've made these for all datatypes.